# How do I stop Outlook 2007 from sending my E-mails to my junk box?

Tags: email, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007

I have been using Outlook 2003 for a long time and never had this problem. Recently I've started using Outlook 2007 and many important e-mails that are not junk mail end up in my junk box.

I have tried adding exception to each one but I have to do this each time. Each time I receive e-mail from someone who is not present in my contact list it ends up in junk mail. How do I stop Outlook sending my mails to junk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Click Tools, Options, Preferences, Junk Email](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/handling-junk-mail-in-outlook-2007-HA010232591.aspx).